# running console application from php

Tags: php, ajax, ubuntu

I have a c++ console application (game) that I'm running on an ubuntu server. I want to access it over the web via  ajax (maybe) and php. The app takes only three different inputs. Y to continue, n to quit or a number 1 to 100. Depending on the input the app will return different strings.

The php function exec() will start the program. Should i use shell_exec() to continuously interact with this app or start the app via proc_open()

Comment: [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) is what you need. Start the command in the background (using `&`) and keep the standard input and output handles (and store the references in the session?) when a user sends data forward that data to the app's input wait for output and send it back to the user.

Comment: Thanks  much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Pass your arguments (y, n...) Values as parameters in command line. That's all for PHP.
You must parse them inside your console application.
To achieve your goal, implement inter process communication IPC, so if the con app is already running send just a message that contain your arguments.
Your job is with c++ not PHP.

Comment: td I want the user to interact via a web browser.  Y might be entered 100 consecutive times. I need  to pass this value each and every time . Also the user may pass different numerical values each and every time as well